# What to pass to super when there are no props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this component:

```
class Logos extends React.Component<{}, LogosState> {
    ...

    public constructor() {
        super({});
        ...
    }
}
```

I have understood from here that I do need to pass arguments to super even when a component has no props.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/20987#issuecomment-339216734

My conclusion was to try the code above. But I get the warning:

```
Warning: Logos(...): When calling super() in `Logos`, make sure to pass up the same props that your component's constructor was passed.
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up doing this. The other answers posted before this were helpful and led me to this solution, but were not complete:

```
class Logos extends React.Component<{}, LogosState> {
    ...

    public constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
}
```

Do it like this or

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this instead.

```
constructor(){
   super()
}
```

In the official document of react, react recommend we use

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
}
```

And the only reason that you should add props is that you want to use this.props in  constructor.If you don't want to use this.props,it's ok not to pass props to super.